# Magento - Duplicate selected filter in ShopBy block

Tags: php, magento

When I click on any filter of my ShopBy block, all works great exept the state.phtml part ("CURRENTLY SHOPPING BY:")

For example if I click on "0,00 € - 99,99 € (150)" [Price], in my ShopBy block I see : PRICE: 0,00 € - 99,99 € three times !

Have you an idea ?

*{Magento ver. 1.7.0.0}*

Comment: please post the code of your state.phtml file

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.  I narrowed it down to the local.xml file I was using.  I renamed it so it would look to the default layout and the problem went away.

I made a custom leftnav and had it in the default as:

```
<reference name="left">
              <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="leftNav" as="leftNav" template="page/html/sidemenu.phtml" before="left"/>               
            </reference>
```

I changed it to:

```
<reference name="left">
              <block type="catalog/navigation" name="leftNav" as="leftNav" template="page/html/sidemenu.phtml" before="left"/>               
            </reference>
```

**type="catalog/navigation"** and the problem went away

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,
In fact, my problem was that my  '" nodes was used by different page, and doesn't load at the same time. But I was wrong.